# why doesn't vagrant provisioner modify ~/.bashrc?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

How can I make the Vagrantfile append the contents of a file to the ~/.bashrc file ?

In my Vagrantfile, I am trying to append the contents of a file /vagrant/dev_env_config to the ~/.bashrc file.

When I run `vagrant up` it outputs the echo statement AND it outputs the expected contents of the ~/.bashrc file.... so I know it's reading the file dev_env_config and APPEARS to be appending it.

However, when I then run `vagrant ssh` and then `cat ~/.bashrc` the ~/.bashrc file is unmodified, it's the default ~/.bashrc file

In other words the mods to ~/.bashrc file are lost somewhere between when the vagrant provison runs and when I run `vagrant ssh`

```
# Vagrantfile

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  ... various cmds to set box and network...
  $install_user_vars = <<SCRIPT
      sudo cat /vagrant/dev_env_config  >> ~/.bashrc
      echo "*** here is the .bashrc file:"
      cat ~/.bashrc
SCRIPT
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $install_user_vars
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what's happening is the provisioning script is run as root (or sudo), so the "~" home location is actually /root rather than the default user home location /home/vagrant.

I can think of a couple ways to solve this:

First (and probably easiest) is to be explicit about the .bashrc path, like:

```
# Vagrantfile

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  ... various cmds to set box and network...
  $install_user_vars = <<SCRIPT
      sudo cat /vagrant/dev_env_config  >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc
      echo "*** here is the .bashrc file:"
      cat /home/vagrant/.bashrc
SCRIPT
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $install_user_vars
end
```

The second option could be to run this part of the provisioning script as a non-privileged user. See the 'privileged' option on the [Shell Scripts](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html) docs page.

Comment: Bingo, making the path explicit works perfectly, thanks! In this case reaplceing all instances of ~/.bashrc with /home/vagrant/.bashrc

Answer (score 2):

A primitive solution is to set the path to `.bashrc` explicitly. As a rule default username of a SSH user (which will be used for `vagrant ssh` action) is `vagrant` so:

```
$install_user_vars = <<SCRIPT
      sudo cat /vagrant/dev_env_config  >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc
      echo "*** here is the .bashrc file:"
      cat /home/vagrant/.bashrc
SCRIPT
```

Also I'm not sure that it's a necessary to use a `sudo` command (in `sudo cat ...`). Probably you don't need it, but it depends on which user is used to run a provision script. I guess it's also `vagrant`.

So if it's really a `vagrant` you could leave the path to `.bashrc` unmodified (`~/.bashrc`), but have to remove `sudo cat ...` command and use simple `cat ...` instead. And it's a more clean solution in my opinion. Because actually we shouldn't use `sudo` (`root`) permissions without need.